# How do I find which repository a package is coming from?

Tags: 12.04, update-manager

When updating in 12.04, this is what I see:

[image: Update]

But then I get this:

[image: Update error]

I have the following PPAs installed:

[image: PPAs]

Which PPA, do you think, could be causing my update error? And what is the problematic PPA (Video4Linux?). I've had these PPAs installed for a while without problems.

Any advice / troubleshooting would be great, thanks.

Comment: If they're on launchpad, they should be considered authenticated.  I think you need to purge and update again.

Comment: I have edited the title slightly, please let me know if I got it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

`apt-cache showpkg <foo_package>` should give you an output that allows you to understand where the packages are comming from.

This is what I get when I run `apt-cache showpkg gedit`:

```
Package: gedit
Versions: 
3.4.1-0ubuntu1 (/var/lib/apt/lists/nl.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise_main_binary-amd64_Packages) (/var/lib/dpkg/status)
 Description Language: 
                 File: /var/lib/apt/lists/nl.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise_main_binary-amd64_Packages
                  MD5: 5091aaf6659e6bf7ca9b32695a59f9cd
 Description Language: en
                 File: /var/lib/apt/lists/nl.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise_main_i18n_Translation-en
                  MD5: 5091aaf6659e6bf7ca9b32695a59f9cd
```

Comment: This comment is not useful and quite complicated for a novice like me.

Comment: How? Are you not trying to find what repo a package is comming from?

Comment: What is "foo package"?

Comment: foo = any package, some package, your package -- it means you replaced that part with the packagename you are interested in.

Comment: And what package name might that be? How would I know what to type there?

Comment: @Gonzoza all the packages in that unauthenticated list of packages? ie `libv4l-0` and so on.

Comment: You're dealing with a novice here. What are "unauthenticated list of packages" and what it is "and so on". I still have no idea what the answer to my question is.